# Why my LibraryCache gets locked with parallel queries?

Tags: oracle, parallel-processing

I am using Oracle 12C, Needed help to understand,

1) I am facing an issue of several sessions in locked state (LibraryCache). Showing me as Parallel queries are running, but I have not set any Parallel clause in DDL of table object.
Only for migration Indexes are created with Parallel clause
But that is only for create Not understand why it is taking for DML also.

2) Also if I assume if that is the case then while running DML from sqleditor its ExecutionPlan shows me noting as parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got an answer through,

http://blog.tanelpoder.com/2007/06/23/a-gotcha-with-parallel-index-builds-parallel-degree-and-query-plans/